# jQuery animate: Split one animation in two parts

Tags: jquery, split, jquery-animate

The following code snippet is performing on smoothe animation:

```
    $('button').animate({
        'margin-top': 123,
        'opacity': 1
    }, 500);
```

Is is somehow possible to split it in two commands without having the effect of queuing the two animations?

```
    jQelems.$divSlideButtonLeft.animate({
        'margin-top': 123,
    }, 500);

    jQelems.$divSlideButtonLeft.animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 500);
```

The aim is to be able to seperate animations for one object in different functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use [the second form](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) of `animate()` and pass `false` in the `queue` option:

```
jQelems.$divSlideButtonLeft.animate({
    "margin-top": 123
}, {
    duration: 500,
    queue: false
});

jQelems.$divSlideButtonLeft.animate({
    opacity: 1
}, {
    duration: 500,
    queue: false
});
```

The documentation says:

> `queue`: A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the
>   effects queue. If `false`, the animation will begin immediately.

Comment: You're the man my friend. I actually tried this parameter before but it didn't work, perhaps my syntax was wrong

Answer (score 0):

you can try 
call the opacity in callback function of you first part animation.

```
$('button').animate({'margin-top': 123,}, 500, function (){
$('button').animate({  'opacity': 1}, 500)
});
```

both animation will happen one after the another.

Comment: I want to completly seperate the two animations calls, they must not be dependant on each other. Hamidi gave the correct answer.